# postgresql RIGHT Join: limit returned rows

Tags: postgresql

I have the following schema:

**expenses**

| id | name, varchar | cost, double | date, DATE | category_id, int f_key | user_id, int f_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pizza | 22.9 | 22/08/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Pool | 34.9 | 23/08/2022 | 2 | 1 |

**categories**

| id | name, varchar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Food |
| 2 | Leisure |
| 3 | Medicine |
| 4 | Fancy food |

*users_categories*(user_id int foreign key, category_id foreign key)

| user_id int f_key | category_id int f_key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

And two users with id 1 and 2.

Relation between user and category is many to many.

**Problem:**

I want to get statistics (total cost amount and count) for all categories. For categories where there are no expenses I want to return 0. Here is my query:

```
SELECT categories.name as name, count(expenses.name) as count, round(SUM(price)::numeric,2) as sum
FROM expenses
Right JOIN categories ON expenses.category_id = categories.id
and expenses.category_id in (
 select users_categories.category_id from users_categories where users_categories.user_id = 1
)
and expenses.id in(
 Select expenses.id from expenses
  join users_categories on expenses.category_id = users_categories.category_id
  and expenses.user_id = 1
  AND (extract(year from date) = 2022 OR CAST(2022 AS int) is null)
  AND (extract(month from date) = 8 OR CAST(8 AS int) is null)
)
GROUP BY categories.id ORDER BY categories.id
```

The response is:

| name | count | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 1 | 22.9 |
| Leisure | 1 | 33.9 |
| Medicine | 0 | null |
| Fancy food | 0 | null |

How I should edit my query to eliminate the last row, because this category doesn't belong to the user 1.

Comment: post sample data  , make it as a script or fiddle ,SO we can work on it?

Comment: @Sund'er, here it is

Comment: @Yurii jjanes is right. because you have `Right JOIN categories ON ` means that all the column/rows related to `categories` will be full displayed. If You want remove/filer some  rows in categoris, you need use `where condition `clause to remove rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you used user_categories as subquery so it will not filter category ids,

Try this Query

```
SELECT categories.name as name,count(expenses.name) as count, coalesce(round(SUM(price)::numeric,2),0) as sum from 
categories 
left join users_categories on users_categories.category_id= categories.id
left join expenses  ON expenses.category_id = categories.id 
AND (extract(year from date) = 2022 OR CAST(2022 AS int) is null)
  AND (extract(month from date) = 8 OR CAST(8 AS int) is null)
where users_categories.user_id='1' 
GROUP BY categories.name,categories.id ORDER BY categories.id
```

OUTPUT :

```
name    count   sum
Food    1   22.90
Leisure     1   34.90
Medicine    0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to move `expenses.category_id in ...` out of the ON condition and into a WHERE clause.

When it is in the ON clause, that means rows which were removed by the in-test just get NULL-fabricated anyway.  You want to remove those rows after the NULL-fabrication is done, so that they remain removed.  But why do you use that in-test anyway?  Seems like it would be much simpler written as another join.

Comment: Moving them to a WHERE condition eliminate all NULL rows, that's not what I want. Replacing IN to `JOIN users_categories on expenses.user_id = users_categories.user_id` does not provide correct result.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you are trying to get the count and sum of expenses for all the categories related to the user_id 1 within the month of august 2022.

Please try out the following query.

```
WITH statistics
    AS (SELECT e.category_id,
               Count(e.*)            AS count,
               Round(Sum(e.cost), 2) AS sum
        FROM   expenses e
        WHERE  e.user_id = 1
               AND ( e.date BETWEEN '01/08/2022' AND '31/08/2022' )
        GROUP  BY e.category_id),
    user_category
    AS (SELECT uc.category_id,
               COALESCE(s.count, 0) AS count,
               COALESCE(s.sum, 0)   AS sum
        FROM   users_categories uc
               LEFT JOIN statistics s
                      ON uc.category_id = s.id
        WHERE  uc.user_id = 1)
SELECT c.NAME,
      u.count,
      u.sum
FROM   categories c
      INNER JOIN user_category u
              ON u.category_id = c.id;
```